# Bulk Export file paths from sharepoint

Tags: hyperlink, filepath, sharepoint-online

I am adding 200+ hyperlinks to an excel file for easier access to sharepoint folders. Rather than manually pulling each one I am trying to bulk export the file paths from a sharepoint folder. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

We can use PnP PowerShell to achieve it.

```
#Config Variables
$SiteURL = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/lz"
$ListName = "DL0906"
$FolderRelativeURL= "/sites/lz/DL0910/Test"
$ExportFile="C:\temp\FileUrls.csv"  
#Get Credentials to connect
$Cred = Get-Credential

Try {
    #Connect to PNP Online
    Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials $Cred

    #Get All Items from the Folder
    $CAMLQuery = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FileDirRef'/><Value Type='Text'>$FolderRelativeURL</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>"
    $FolderItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName -Query $CAMLQuery

    $FileCollection = @() 
    ForEach($Item in $FolderItems)
    {
        $ExportFileUrl = New-Object PSObject 
        $ExportFileUrl | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "File URL" -value $Item["FileRef"]
        $FileCollection += $ExportFileUrl
    }   
    $FileCollection | Export-CSV $ExportFile -NoTypeInformation
}
catch {
    write-host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" -foregroundcolor Red
}
```

Refer to: [SharePoint Online: Get All Files from a Folder using PowerShell](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/05/sharepoint-online-get-all-files-from-folder-using-powershell.html)